# Conditional label for selected stack bar chart in facet ggplots 2

Tags: ggplot2, label, bar-chart, facet-wrap, geom-text

I am looking for a help to display labels for a selected stack bar, e.g. "Net impacts" stack, in the facet_wrap stack figure below. I tried to use `geom_text(aes(label=ifelse()))` but it does not work. 
Any suggestion would be grateful. Thanks in advance. 
[Stack-bars chart Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JBDt.png)

Update: So, instead of displaying the labels for a selected stack-bar, I've just come up with the combination of stack-bar and point chart figure [Stack-bars and Points chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF27z.png). I am satisfied with the yellow points presenting sum of stack-bars at each column, though it would be much better if these values can be showed on each bar. Any suggestion please?!

In addition, is it possible to show scientific number as labels for the points/stack-bars?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you want to label?  Do you just want to show labels based upon the one stack for "Net impacts"?  If the information is in your dataframe, but you only want to show labels according to one column in that dataframe for "Net impacts", I would suggest passing a filtered version of your dataset to the geom via something like `geom_text(data=my.filtered.dataset..., mapping=aes(...`.

Comment: Hi @chemdork123, thanks a lot. I've just able to display the label for a selected stack following your suggestion.